# Can Read-Host be overloaded?

Tags: c#, powershell

When writing a custom PowerShell host, can Read-Host (ie. PSHostUserInterface.ReadLine) be overloaded to return an object instead of a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want the user to give you a specific type, it's usually best to let PowerShell do the type-casting. For instance:

```
function get-duration {
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [TimeSpan]$HowLongDidItLast
    )

 return $HowLongDidItLast 
 }
```

OR

```
 [TimeSpan](Read-Host "How long did it last?")
```

Would return a timespan object, assuming the user entered something like a number or "2:30" ...

However, in the case of Excel.Range ... it's an interface, so PowerShell isn't going to deal with it, and you won't be able to prompt for it directly.

As a general rule, I would avoid interfaces as parameter types in PowerShell cmdlets or functions because of that lack coersion...

Comment: How would I approach creating cmdlets that involve Excel objects?

Comment: If you expose some special automatic variables, or put some extra properties or methods on your $Host.PrivateData, you can write cmdlets that interact with those. Take a look at Nuget or at PoshConsole + PowerBoots ... both of these expose internals of the host to cmdlets that either don't work, or work differently when they're run from another host.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you looking to accomplish?  E.g., what would you want read-host to return exactly?

You won't be able to overload read-host through the PSHost* interfaces; however, you may be able to accomplish what you want by creating a [proxy function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/01/04/extending-and-or-modifing-commands-with-proxies.aspx) on the read-host cmdlet that is available in your custom host...

Comment: I am trying to create a host that communicates with Excel, and it would be nice if read-host could return an Excel range object I could then manupulate.

Comment: would the user type in a cell range at a prompt?  i'm wondering if you couldn't encode the range as a string: > read-host | convertto-range?

Comment: I am trying to implement something like that right now. Excel.Application.InputBox() function lets the user select a range and it looks like it can return it as a string, that would save some typing.